# Multiple domain listener for Application Load Balancer ingress controller

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm working with the K8s AWS Load Balancer Controller (https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller) and need some advice.  I need it to respond to two different hostnames with two different wildcard SSL certificates and direct traffic to the same target group.

Here's my current ingress.yaml file:

```yaml
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: gradle
  name: gradle-proxy-dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: "<scrubbed cert ARN>"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: "<scrubbed>"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: "ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /info/version
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: "200"
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: routing.http2.enabled=true
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: gradle-proxy
              servicePort: 80
```

It currently has no trouble responding to the URL gradle.internal.domain.com, but throws an SSL error when I direct traffic for gradle.new.domain.com, which makes sense since the only certificate is for *.internal.domain.com.

In the EC2 console, I can attach a second certificate and add a rule to forward traffic for host "gradle.new.domain.com" to to the created target group, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to capture that in the ingress yaml configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution here was that I didn't need any fancy rules, I just needed to add the second wildcard SSL certificate to the ingress configuration.